# Can't not access apache server-status page when i add configuration for load balancing

Tags: apache-2.2

apache 2.2
censtos 5.5

I have include following configuration in httpd.conf to access server status page.

```
<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>

I have successfully accessed the status page by url  (http://127.0.0.1/server-statup)
```

Now i have include following configuration for load balancing in httpd.conf

```
ProxyPass / balancer://sakaiCluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=off timeout=120
<Proxy balancer://sakaiCluster>
BalancerMember ajp://172.16.11.12:8009 route=s1     
BalancerMember ajp://172.16.11.13:8009 route=s2 
</Proxy>
```

but this time when i try to access the apache server status page, it give me error.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /server-status
type Status report
message /server-status
description The requested resource (/server-status) is not available.
Apache Tomcat/5.5.33
```

any one can help in this problem.

Comment: How are you accessing the sever status page? (address)

Comment: I have define ip in config as 127.0.0.1 and acessing from this url http://127.0.0.1/server-status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the /server-status URL is also forwarded to your Tomcat cluster. You should exclude it:

```
ProxyPass /server-status !
ProxyPass / balancer://sakaiCluster/ stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=off timeout=120
<Proxy balancer://sakaiCluster>
BalancerMember ajp://172.16.11.12:8009 route=s1     
BalancerMember ajp://172.16.11.13:8009 route=s2 
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Win! @user198926 Could you also flag my answer as the correct one so the question is marked as closed? Thanks in advance.